# display different format of date in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting date from DB like 30/01/2018 . 
and when I fetch it to display it shows us like same. I would like to get it as 30 Jan 2017 . I can not change DB information, it is coming from client side. I am using Angular JS and ionic

Comment: Are you trying to display this in a label or something?

Comment: its in a DIV and i have been using ng-repeat

Comment: You could use momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

### In an HTML template

```
<span>{{ dateVar | date : 'dd MMM yyyy' }}</span>
```

### In JavaScript code

```
$filter('date')(dateVar, 'dd MMM yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ionic-datetime component

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: He is using Ionic1/AngularJS not ionic2+

Comment: This is for ionic2